# Update progress text while executing one custom action?

Tags: c#, wix

I want to update the progress text when executing one custom action. I have done the following things:

1. declare my custom action to be deferred
2. use below code to reset the progress bar

   ```
   private static void ResetProgress(Session session)
   {
       Record record = new Record(4);
       record[1] = "0";
       record[2] = "1000";
       record[3] = "0";
       record[4] = "0";
       session.Message(InstallMessage.Progress, record);
   }
   ```
3. use below code to move the progress bar:

   ```
   private static void NumberOfTicksPerActionData(Session session, int ticks)
   {
       Record record = new Record(3);
       record[1] = "1";
       record[2] = ticks.ToString();
       record[3] = "1";
       session.Message(InstallMessage.Progress, record);
   }
   ```
4. use below code to update the progress text:

   ```
   private static void DisplayActionData(Session session, string message)
   {
       Record record = new Record(1);
       record[1] = message;
       session.Message(InstallMessage.ActionData, record);
   }
   ```

However, I have failed to update the progress text and move the progress bar.

Any one can help me?
If this custom action needs to process sequential actions, how should I update the status 
on the progress bar while executing this custom action.

I know that I can use

```
<ProgressText Action="UnzipDataBase">Now installing database files, this may take a few minutes!</ProgressText>
```

to set progress text to tell what this custom action is doing. But how to update the status while executing this custom action?

Answer (score 1):

Did you put the ProgressText inside UI element? For example

```
<UI>
   <ProgressText Action="UnzipDataBase">Now installing database files, this may take a few minutes!</ProgressText>
</UI>
```